# Disable Intellij auto copy to clipboard

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard

I like using Intellij. It has many great features, but I also dislike the fact that it auto-copy selection to clipboard during some actions (selection with some mouse events, with deletion, some keyboard shortcuts I guess other than "copy" etc, I don't know exactly which ones, but it does happen for sure). Is there a way to disable that?

Of course, I can use "paste from history" but it is a pain: I know that I have copied the good text with the keyboard shortcut, why another motion has overriden my clipboard? I have to right click and check etc... it is way too slow.

I would like only "right click copy" and "keyboard shortcut copy" to be the only motions that can copy content to clipboard.

I have the problem on Windows 7 64 bits, Intellij 12, but I had it on Intellij 11 too.

For instance: shift+del (delete line) auto-copy content to clipboard.

Comment: I have not seen this happen (Windows 7 64-bit, Mac OSX Mountain Lion + Intellij 12.1.5 and 13.x). Which OS are you using and which Intellij IDEA version? The 'auto-copy' you describe is reminiscent of Linux. Do you have a clipboard manager installed perchance (Ditto for example)?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 64, from time to time I have this problem, I'll try to define a correct case to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> will delete a line without copying it to clipboard. I can hardly think of other operations with this side-effect. I.e. <kbd>Ctrl+Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Delete</kbd> which delete a word to the left or right of a cursor don't have it.

Update: there is also <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd> that will be bring out a clipboard history popup in case one occasionally overwrites buffer content.

Answer (score 20):

To disable this in the terminal -

Settings > Tools > Terminal: Uncheck "Copy to clipboard on selection"

This was most painful for me when using the terminal, when i'm trying to paste jira tickets into my commit message and it gets overwritten because I applied too much pressure to the track pad.

Answer (score 19):

Shift-Delete is a shortcut for "cut". 

To disable:

- Go to Settings -> Keymap -> search for cut
- right-click on found "cut" action, select "remove shift-delete
- search for delete line
- right-click on found "Delete line" action, add keyboard shortcut, press Shif-delete, hit ok

  It might warn you on possible conflict with maven's exclude extension action

Hope it helps

Comment: Removing "shift-delete" helped me. It happened on every "delete" without pressing shift. Probably a bug...

Comment: Thanks!! This was driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Cut: then right mouse click and "Remove Shift+Delete"

Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > Edit > Cut/Copy/Paste Action: then right mouse click and "Remove Shift+Delete"

---

To turn Shift+Delete action without 'copy/cut'

Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Delete Line: then right mouse click and "Add Keyboard Shortcut"